# Chaining Promise - Await Async Foreach loop

Tags: node.js, foreach, async-await

I am struggling to get the understand how chaining of promise actually works.

I am trying to call API A - to get all books. Then I want to call API B - which give me a description of books.

But on Bookdescribe method (see the last section of codes), when I did a debug, the Promise Value is undefined.

How do I return the value back to path /getAllbooks?

index.js

```
.get('getAllBooks', '/getAllBooks', async (ctx) => {
            try {
var util = require('../util')
var result = await util.getAllBooks(conn)

}
```

util.js - getAllbooks Method

```
async function getAllBooks(conn) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var books = []

            conn.describeGlobal(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err)
                }
                console.log('No of Objects ' + res.sobjects.length)
                res.sobjects.forEach(function (sobject) {
                     if (sobject.type == "book"){
                        books.push(sobject)  }
                })    
                resolve(books)
            })
        }).then(result => booksDescribe(conn, result))
    }
```

util.js - booksDescribe method

```
    async function booksDescribe(conn, result) {
    var i = 0;
        var something = await Promise.all(result.map(async (item) =>{
           await conn.sobject(item).describe(function (err, meta) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log("What? " + err);
                }

                const content = meta.description

                return content

            })  
        }))
}
```

Comment: Where's your async `forEach()` loop?  I don't see one.

Comment: It seems very likely that this `await conn.sobject(item).describe(function (err, meta) {...)` does not work.  `await` only does something useful when it's awaiting a promise and `.describe()` when you pass it a callback likely does not return a promise.

Comment: apologise. I was using foreach then i change to map, see bookdescribe

Comment: Well, then see my previous comment.  That `await` does nothing useful.

Comment: yeah good point.. let me change that

Comment: why are you doing `res.sobjects.forEach` just to push each item to **another** array?  can you not just do `resolve(res.sobjects);`?

Comment: I removed some logic in there for the posting. basically in that section of codes, i was doing an if else statement to sort the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 async function booksDescribe(conn, result) {
    var i = 0;
        var something = await Promise.all(result.map(async (item) =>{
           await conn.sobject(item).describe().then(response  => {
                return(response)

            })  
        }))
}
```